# How to get the available records in MySQL Table, if we match multiple records?

Tags: mysql, nestjs, typeorm

Creating a group of users by their numbers. I have two tables Users and Groups. Groups will be created when we have a number of user's phone numbers is available in the records.

User Tables

```
uid
name
mobile
```

Groups Tables

```
groupId
title
uid
mobileList
```

I want to check my contact list, is my phone number is available in the records like I have more than 300 numbers how to check the records in Users->mobile return the list of the available numbers.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.   Use n=3 instead of 300 and give us example input & output.  My guess is "my phone number" is one `select * from user where mobile = ?'.   What's the primary and secondary keys i.e. user.uid = groups.uid?

Comment: Provide a sample. CREATE TABLE for both tables. INSERT INTO with sample data. Desired result for this data (provide 8-10 rows per table and the result assuming 3 rows per group). And specify precise server version.